# Run pkg within dmg C++

Tags: c++, macos, dmg, pkg-file

Tried searching on Google but can't seem to find any information.

I need to execute a pkg file which exists within a dmg file via code. Reason is software update. I download an update via my application (which is a dmg) and need to run it. On Windows this is pretty straightforward: run the exe. Having trouble figuring out how to achieve this on a Mac.

As far as frameworks go, I'm using wxWidgets with cocoa (if that helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this directly with cocoa APIs, but you can use external commands to do it: use `/usr/bin/hdiutil attach /path/to/image.dmg` to mount the disk image, then something like `/usr/sbin/installer -package /Volumes/mountedvolume/installer.pkg -target /` to install the package (see `man installer` for more information and options). Note that if the package requires admin rights to install, you'll need to run the `installer` command as root.

EDIT: to get the full path of the mounted volume, you'll probably have to parse the output of `hdiutil`. It'll look something like this, although it'll depend significantly on the format of the disk image:

```
/dev/disk2              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk2s2            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/mountedvolume
```

Comment: How do you obtain `mountedvolume` after the call to `hdiutil`?

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Turns out `<mountedvolume>` is the same as what is set using the `-volname` parameter when the dmg was built using `hdiutil`. Since my pkg file is a gui based installer, I use `open` instead of `installer` for the second command.

Comment: @Ash you should probably parse the output of hdiutil just to be sure -- if /Volumes/imagename already exists, it'll be mounted as /Volumes/imagename 1 (with a space), so if you try to open the package from /Volumes/imagename you'll either get file not found, or you'll open the wrong package.